# Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ and suppose that $n \geq 4$. Then there exists non-negative integers $x, y$ such that $n = 2x + 5y$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

> Base cases:
>
> If $n = 4$, then we set $x = 2, y = 0$ and get $n = 2(2) + 5(0)$, as desired.
>
> If $n = 5$, then we set $x = 0, y = 1$ and get $n = 2(0) + 5(1)$, as desired.
>
> General case: Now assume that $n \geq 6$.
>   Note that $(n − 2) \in \mathbb{Z}_+$ with $n − 2 \geq 4$ (since $n \geq 6, n\in \mathbb{Z}_+$), so we may apply
>   induction to $n − 2$.
>
> Hence there exists non-negative integers $x', y'$ such that:
>
> $n − 2 = 2x' + 5y'$
>   $\iff n = 2x' + 2 + 5y'$
>   $\iff n = 2(x' + 1) + 5y'$.
>
> Let $x = x' + 1$ and $y = y'$. 
>   Then $x, y$ are non-negative integers with $n = 2x + 5y$.

Solving previous induction proofs I have been able to apply induction to $n-1$.  In the solution for this example induction is applied to $n-2$.  Are there certain cases where induction should be applied to one over the other or is this just a more efficient method?

Comment: Note if $n=2+2 + $ "other $2$s and $5s$", then we can replace the $2+2$ by $5$ to obtain $n+1$. If $n=5+$ "other stuff" then we can replace $5$ by $2+2+2$ to get $n+1$. Now you just have to show that for $n\geq 4$ these are the only two cases

Comment: This problem can be done by applying induction to $n - 1$, as @JihoonKang indicated.  However, the objective here is to show that every integer $n \geq 4$ can be expressed in the form $n = 2x + 5y$.  The author chose this method since it involves fewer steps.

Comment: @JihoonKang Thanks!